# Comparing two rows according to specific string

Tags: excel, vba

So i've been trying to wrap my head around this for weeks now and have tried many things but nothing that works for my case, I have two sheets with "similar" Structures( same amount of columns and same rows, achieved through MS Power Query). Here is the code, P.S took the foundation from somewhere else:

```
Function CompareSheets_Adv(sh1Name$, sheet2name$) As Boolean
Dim vstr As String
Dim vData As Variant
Dim vitm As Variant
Dim vArr As Variant
Dim v()



Dim Range1, Range2, Range3 As Range
Dim a As Long
Dim b As Long
Dim c As Long


On Error GoTo CompareSheetsERR

vData = Sheets(sh1Name$).Range("A2:E500").Value

 With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    .CompareMode = 1`
    
    ReDim v(1 To UBound(vData, 2))
    
    For a = 2 To UBound(vData, 1)
        
        For b = 1 To UBound(vData, 2)
            vstr = vstr & Chr(2) & vData(a, b)
            v(b) = vData(a, b)
        Next
        .item(vstr) = v
        vstr = ""
        
    Next
    
    vData = Sheets(sheet2name$).Range("A2:E500").Value

    
    For a = 2 To UBound(vData, 1)
        
        For b = 1 To UBound(vData, 2)
            vstr = vstr & Chr(2) & vData(a, b)
            v(b) = vData(a, b)
        Next
    
        If .Exists(vstr) Then
            .item(vstr) = Empty
            Else
            .item(vstr) = v
        End If
        
        vstr = ""
    Next
    
    For Each vitm In .Keys
        If IsEmpty(.item(vitm)) Then
        .Remove vitm
        End If
    Next
        
    vArr = .Items
    c = .count

 End With

 With Sheets("Results").Range("a2").Resize(, UBound(vData, 2))

.Cells.Clear
.Value = vData


If c > 0 Then
    .Offset(1).Resize(c).Value = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(vArr))
End If

  End With    
   CompareSheets_Adv = True
  Exit Function
CompareSheetsERR:
CompareSheets_Adv = False

 End Function
```

This code uses a dictionary and arrays to compare both sheets and then displays results on Worksheet "Results". This how it looks like with my dummy entries:
[image: Results]

My issue currently is editing my function in a way that I keep the data integrity intact (Identifiers must always match, according to description too when comparing rows) while comparing the function only for the differences(reference of Sheet1="SiteData") . I might have been approaching this wrong from the get go, resorting to asking my question here is a last hope thing for me. I'm not very adept at Excel VBA. Appreciate any and all kinds of help and feedback.

Update:
Currently trying to create a hash string identifier for the row and using that to compare the rows regardless of the order, as long as the hash strings match(assuming hash string is the same for two strings).

Comment: Note that `Dim Range1, Range2, Range3 As Range` only defines `Range3 As Range` but the other 2 variables are of type `Variant`. In VBA you need to specify a type for **every** variable otherwise it is `Variant` by default: `Dim Range1 As Range, Range2 As Range, Range3 As Range`

Comment: Thanks for the input! Changed the declarations for Range. Sadly my issue is not resolved by that, back to the code it is :)

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear to me. It is not clear how your original data looks like (that you want to compare) nor is clear what you are actually doing. Can you please [edit] and include example source data for the "result" in your screenshot? And explain what exactly you want to compare (pick at least one example dataset out of your example data) and explain what you expect to do with it.

Comment: Forgive me, I will rewrite and edit my question to make it clearer.